# Apache camel exchange Id

Tags: spring-boot, logging, apache-camel, trace

I use camel.exchangeId in logs but I see that for every request it's the same ID.
I need unique ID (I thought exchangeId is unique) so I added breadcrumbId but I have async route and it's not ok sometimes (I mean I got another Id as it works).

How this exchangeId works? Is it one Id for every request created during first application initialization?

Does anyone had such case, how to "track" request using Spring Boot, Apache Camel with sync and async routes?

Answer (score 1):

The exchange id is unique per exchange for its entire lifecycle.

The breadcrumb id is unique per breadcrumb, and then intention is that the same breadcrumb can be transfered over network and use on the other end, so you can correlate the events. However its Camel specific.

Today there are distributed tracing systems, you can use that can track per request (spans), such as micrometer. Camel has integration with these such as the recent blog post: https://camel.apache.org/blog/2023/04/camel-observation/